# such little amount of sleep

Tags: quantifiers

a. You won't be able to perform well with that little sleep.

a1. You won't be able to perform well with such little sleep.

(that small amount of sleep)

---

b. You want to sleep five hours a night. That little sleep won't be sufficient for you.

b1. You want to sleep five hours a night. Such little sleep won't be sufficient for you.

c. You only have two dollars. You can't buy a proper meal in this city with that little money.

c1. You only have two dollars. You can't buy a proper meal in this city with such little money.

Are the above sentences grammatically correct?

I think they work, but are somewhat uncommon.

Comment: We say _so little_ rather than _such little_.

Answer (score 3):

You should use "so little" in these examples.

You can also say "such a small amount of", but that sounds quite stilted and awkward in many situations.

Use "so little" with uncountable nouns like sleep, money, milk, coffee, paint, etc.

Use "so few" with countable plural nouns such as apples, oranges, people, dogs etc.

Comment: Using 'such' instead of 'so' seems to be one of those catch 'em out phrases all non-English natives fall for.